# Replacing Mulesoft VM Connector (in memory) with Java Spring Open source solution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, executorservice

We have got some legacy applications which are using Mulesoft SOAP implementation for creating Skelton and Stub which I have migrated to Spring Boot and using some other libraries successfully. But we are using Mule VM Connector with in memory queue to post logging data (and on consumer side it uses Spring JDBC template to post logging data to some 3rd party system which we are trying to keep as it is and keep changes minimal). The VM Connector logic is kind of decoupled from original application so to not slow actual SOAP calls and really don't care if they timeout and are lost in a high volume period.

So for this I'm looking into different solution like using some in-memory Message Broker Spring Integration or in-memory Active MQ. or can we use Spring JMS as well?

Or on other side of using ASYNC call as that's the main purpose Mulesoft VM connector are fulfilling but can in that case as we are not changing the underlying Java logic which uses Spring JDBC template do we have to think of thread safety?

What you think is the best approach, should we use some in-memory Message Broker and which one?
Or should convert to use ASYNC?